# Django -- Dynamically showing Images that are created daily

Tags: python, django

What I want to accomplish is have an separate application generate graphs that will be placed in a directory of my Django project. Then in my template loop through and display all the graphs from that directory on the webpage. The generated graphs will be refreshed daily and will be of varying numbers depending on the day (so some days it could be 20 and/or the next it could be 50).

Option 1)
I don't think I want to use django manage.py collectstatic everyday. I've never gotten to the point of deploying a Django project to a server but my assumption is that I would have to collectstatic manually everyday on the server (which I could be thoroughly off on here)

Option 2)
I've tried creating a model [Model Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eueeM.png). The Char field is just my relative path to the picture. From there in my views I'm to rendering the path in the index(request) [View Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6A8Q7.png). From there in my template I'm trying to loop through the picture relative paths and show them [Template Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzczW.png). When I remove photos = Photo.objects.all() & the {% for img in photos %} in the template the page does load [Webpage working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6Ek5.png). However when I run it with all those parts in there I get a blank webpage with "what do you want to do with index" at the bottom. [Webpage not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bihJY.png)

Interested to hear if there are any better way of doing this . I'm not trying to user upload an image field because the amount of graphs will be substantial.

Details on Option 2:

---Notes---
Top Lvl Directory is--chartingtest-project
chartingtest is the project
sectors is the name of the app
media folder is a folder in the top level directory, not within the project or test folder

models.py in sectors app contains

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    photoname = models.ImageField()
```

views.py in sectors app contains

```
from .models import Photo

def index(request):
    pets = Pets.objects.all()
    photos = Photo.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'pets': pets}, {'photos': photos})
```

index.html template

```
{% load static %}

<H1>Hello World Index!</H1>

#Testing bringing in variables from a model (2020/05/07 Works!)
<ul>
{% for pet in pets %}
  <li>{{pet.name}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>


# ************************************
# This is where I'm trying display generated pictures from the media folder
# ************************************
<ul>
{% for img in photos %}
  <li>
    <img src="chart1s/{{img.image.url}}" />
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>


#Testing Static Image (2020/05/08 Works!)
<img src="{% static "OIP.jpg" %}"/>
<img src="{% static "temp_fig_00.png" %}"/>
```

settings.py in chartingtest project folder

```
#Media ROOT
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that using static files will not work, by their name static files are not supposed to change.

The solution is to create a media folder and have your application save the graphs to that folder. Your model picture should point to that folder. Like you said, in your templates you can then iterate over that model to display all the graphs.

In production, you should create a cloud storage bucket and save your images there. Then make sure your settings.py directs any requests for images to your storage bucket.

Your picture model should use models.ImageField(), not a typical CharField, `image = models.ImageField()`. In your template as you iterate, you should call each image with `<img src="{{ picture.image.url }}"`

Apart from that, I would need to look in depth at the code to see what's going on, and I don't click links on stackoverflow posts. If you'd post the code in a comment might be able to take a closer link, but try those things first!

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the taking the time to comment! I appreciate that very much. I  tried implementing your suggestions today. I edited my initial response above to include the code as of this post (Any post I do in the future I'll exclude the pictures -- thanks for that tip). I'm somewhat stuck implementing the part where you talk about "Your model picture should point to that folder." Once I have the media folder set up in the main project directory, with the media root and media url in the project directory, I don't understand how to get the Image field to point to media/charts1

Comment: That looks good to me! So when you generate your graph or whatever image it is, you should save that image to your media folder. Then, with your model, set photo.photoname = ['image_name'], or if in a sub directory chart1s, ['/charts1s/' + 'image_name']. In your template where it calls the variable in your for loop, it should point to the media location. If this is still not working, my guess is that your for loop should say <src = "{{img.photoname.url}}">, as thats what you used in your model.

Comment: To find bugs, first make sure your images are saving where they should be. Then, go into your models on the admin site, and look at what the value for photoname is. If that url is off, you need to change how you set the photoname accordingly.

Comment: Hi Alex, apologize for the late response, work got real busy the last 2 weeks. Tried implementing the above and I'm getting errors when trying to make migrations. I have the pictures in my Media/Charts1 folder. Can you list out the code for the model, because something isn't clicking for me to get it to work. If I change in the Model Photo, the line photoname = models.ImageField() to photo.photoname = ['/charts1s/' + 'image_name'] I don't can't seem to understand how it would grab dynamically the relative paths of the images the external generated saved pics in the media/charts1 folder.